# Eu consigo criar uma tabela no mysql que mostre a idade da pessoa subtraindo o ano de hoje - o ano de nascimento dela?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

**Pergunta:**  Eu consigo criar uma tabela no mysql que mostre a idade da pessoa subtraindo o ano de hoje menos o ano de nascimento dela?

```
   create table idade2 (ID auto_increment Primary key, data_nasc date, idade int as ((year(curdate() - year(data_nasc)) stored);
```

Pode ser assim?

Comment: Não adianta só subtrair o ano. Se uma pessoa nasceu em dezembro de 2000, em janeiro de 2018 ela ainda não tem 18 anos (que é o resultado que vc obteria se só subtraísse os anos). Você deve levar em conta o mês e o dia também. Para diferença de datas, use [`TIMESTAMPDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) ou [`DATEDIFF`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-datediff-function.php)

Comment: Outro detalhe sobre cálculo de idades é com relação a anos bissextos: se alguém nasceu em 29 de fevereiro de 2000, por exemplo. Em 28 de fevereiro de 2018 essa pessoa já tem 18 anos? Ou só em 1 de março? (já que em 2018 não existe o dia 29 de fevereiro). Algumas APIs consideram que em 28/02/2018 a pessoa já completou 18 anos, outras consideram que só em 1 de março. Não sei o que `TIMESTAMPDIFF` e `DATEDIFF` fazem nesses casos, mas é um teste interessante de se fazer.

Comment: A resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Comment: Estas coisas se resolvem por 'functions' ... https://www.codigoexpresso.com.br/Home/Postagem/140

Answer (score 0):

O melhor seria você trazer a idade em um `SELECT` da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(data_nasc) - (RIGHT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 5) < RIGHT(data_nasc, 5)) as idade
  FROM TABELA
```

Não é muito bom guardar atributos de cálculo em tabelas a menos que você tenha para fazê-lo.